# How to Update a property from another window using inotifypropertychanged event in wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, datacontext, inotifypropertychanged

I have two Usercontrols in my Application, one being Mainwindow and another being LoginWindow. Label in Mainwindow.xaml is bond to "UserName" which should be updated from LoginWindow.

MainWindow.Xaml

```
<Grid>
        <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Content="UserName: " FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <Label Content="{Binding UserName}"/>
        </StackPanel>

            <Button Width="200" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Content="Open Login Window" Click="Button_Click" />

        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Mainwindow.xaml.cs 
displays on the loginwindow

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            LoginWindow loginwin = new LoginWindow();
            var host = new Window();
            host.Content = loginwin;
            host.Show();
        }
```

On successful login, UserName shall be displayed onto Mainwindow.

In LoginWindow, i just placed a button which trigger update of UserName to Mainwindow.

LoginWindow.xaml.cs

```
private LoginClass UserObj { get; set; }

        private void Login_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            UserObj = new LoginClass { Username = "From LoginWindow" };
            // How can i update the control <label content > in another userrcontrol 
        }
```

LoginClass.cs where INotifyPropertyChnaged event is implemented

```
 private string _username;

        public string Username
        {
            get { return _username; }
            set
            {
                _username = value;
                onPropertyChnaged("Username");
            }
        }

        private void onPropertyChnaged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    }
```

Program is working as expected if i raise the change of username from Mainwindow giving Datacontext to the object of LoginClass.

UI on MainWindow is getting updated when i change property from Mainwindow itslef .

```
    private LoginClass UserObj { get; set; }    
    private void Button_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
                {
                    UserObj = new LoginClass { Username = "From MainWindow" };
this.DataContext = UserObj;
                    // INotifyPropertyChanged implementation is working fine as i am giving datacontext to UserObj to get updated 
                }
```

How to update the UI from another window using Inotifypropertychnaged event.

I am trying this since last 4 hours .. Request you help please.

Thanks a ton !

Comment: Hello. I think your Databinding is not very efficient: when you want to update the name, you are actually creating a new instance of your LoginClass wich will break the databing link. => Create one instance only of you LoginClass, bind it to the two windows, and update the UserName only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both windows should use the same `DataContext`, i.e. you should only create a single instance of `LoginClass`:

**MainWindow:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    LoginClass UserObj = new LoginClass { Username = "From MainWindow" };

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = UserObj;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LoginWindow loginwin = new LoginWindow();
        loginWin.DataContext = UserObj;
        var host = new Window();
        host.Content = loginwin;
        host.Show();
    }
}
```

**LoginWindow:**

```
private void Login_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var viewModel = DataContext as LoginClass;
    viewModel.Username = "From LoginWindow"
}
```

Comment: I am getting null reference exception. viewModel is showing null .. any idea on this please

Comment: Then you haven't set the DataContext as I told you to: loginWin.DataContext = UserObj;